# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently building a clone of HackerNews and am encountering the following error:

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:591 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null"

found in

---> <Homepage> at src/components/New.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

I'm not sure how this error is occuring! Has anyone out there encountered this before? 
Does this mean the error is in New.vue? Here is that code:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Item from '@/components/Item'
export default {
  name: 'Homepage',
  components: {
    'item': Item
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      err: '',
      stories: []
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/newstories.json')
      .then((result) => {
        this.results = result.data.slice(0, 10)
        this.results.forEach(element => {
          axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + element + '.json')
            .then((result) => {
              this.stories.push(result)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err)
            })
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => { this.err = err })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Btw, my code compiles okay

Comment: Show the HTML that uses your `data()`. The one from `New.vue`.

Comment: <template>
  <div>
    <h2>Homepage</h2>
    <item v-for="story in stories" :key="story.data.id" :story="story"/>
  </div>
</template>

Comment: `<item v-for="story in stories" :key="story.data.id" :story="story" v-if="stories.length" />`

Comment: You have a `story` object without a `.data` property. Look at the JSON response to see what's up.

Comment: Okay, that might've helped, however the error has changed to...

Comment: ---> <Item> at src/components/Item.vue
       <Homepage> at src/components/New.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>

Comment: I'm pulling in the data from HackerNews, so is there a problem there, with the json?

Comment: `if (!result.data) return`; should  handle the unexpected. Put that before processing the results in your success callback.